# is it possible to make setup installation for WebService?

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

is it possible to make setup installation for WebService ?

that the installation will make the Virtual directory + the IIS setup ?

if it possible, how to do it ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87h5xz7x.aspx)

To deploy the Web service using a Web Setup project

On the File menu, point to Add, and then click New Project.

Select the Other node, then the Setup and Deployment Projects node, and then click Web Setup Project.

In the Name box, type TempConvert1WebSetup, and then click OK.

Note:
By default, the installer uses the deployment project name when creating the virtual directory on your deployment server.
In the left pane of the File System Editor, select Web Application Folder. For more information, see File System Editor.

In Solution Explorer, right-click TempConvert1WebSetup, point to Add, and then click Project Output.

In the Add Project Output Group dialog box, select Content Files. For more information, see How to: Add and Remove Project Outputs in the File System Editor.

The Content Files group consists of the following files for the Web service: Service1.asmx, Global.asax, and Web.config. For more information, see How to: Deploy Web Services in Managed Code.

Click OK.

In Solution Explorer, right-click the TempConvert1WebSetup project, and then on the shortcut menu, click Build.

This creates a Windows Installer file in the local project directory. Executing this file installs the Web application.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [IIS WMI Provider](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/9041b0a5-c314-46d9-8f56-01506687f357.mspx?mfr=true).